# Using matplotlib to annotate certain points

Tags: python, matplotlib

While I can hack together code to draw an XY plot, I want some additional stuff:

- Vertical lines that extend from the X axis to a specified distance upward
- text to annotate that point, proximity is a must (see the red text)
- the graph to be self-contained image: a 800-long sequence should occupy 800 pixels in width (I want it to align with a particular image as it is an intensity plot)

[image]

How do I make such a graph in mathplotlib?

Comment: I don't quite follow your 3rd point, do you mean you want to specify the size of the saved image, or to crop the axis off, or something else?

Comment: Isn't this http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate
what you want ?

Comment: In my specific case, I want it (intensity projection of a source image) to fit an 800*600 space, just below the 800*600 source image

Comment: [savefig](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig), takes `figsize`, and `dpi` arguments. So you can set the size no probs, also you'll probably want to turn the axes off.

Comment: This would introduce scaling artifacts and might look extremely ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
data = (0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 7, 8, 6, 6)
ax.plot(data, 'r-', linewidth=4)

plt.axvline(x=5, ymin=0, ymax=4.0 / max(data), linewidth=4)
plt.text(5, 4, 'your text here')
plt.show()
```

Note, that somewhat strangely the `ymin` and `ymax` values run from `0 to 1`, so require normalising to the axis

[image]

---

**EDIT:** The OP has modified the code to make it more OO:

```
fig = plt.figure()
data = (0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 7, 8, 6, 6)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(data, 'r-', linewidth=4)
ax.axvline(x=5, ymin=0, ymax=4.0 / max(data), linewidth=4)
ax.text(5, 4, 'your text here')
fig.show()
```