# Histogram show values of vertical lines in legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

[image]

Can I show the values of vertical lines(dashed) in legends or annotate it somewhere, how?

Here is the code for dashed line

```
plt.hist(df['wt_avg_delay'], bins=50, color='lightblue', edgecolor='black')
plt.axvline(df['wt_avg_delay'].mean(), color='orange', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.axvline(-19, color='green', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.axvline(27 color='red', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
```

Comment: Yes. How? It depends, how you created the dashed lines. We don't know because you have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Mr.T updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Still not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, but you can create custom legends: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416749/8881141

Comment: Or you annotate your line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10500375/8881141

Comment: I can annotate but here the data may changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? Interactively in the graph? This is not included in your question. Or from graph to graph? This is shown in the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to annotate is probably by using `plt.text()`:

```
plt.text(x, y, 'annotation')
```

Alternatively you can just add a label to the lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
p = 2.5


plt.hist(x, label='data')
plt.axvline(p, color='g', label=str(p))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]